# Why does glUnProject(...) return -1.0?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, coordinate-transformation

I'm just trying to transform window coordinates to object coordinates in OpenGL using gluUnproject().

I catch the X and Y coordinates (winX and winY) of the glut window correctly using:

```
glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseMove);
```

and then I set winZ using

```
glReadPixels(int (winX), int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ)
```

Then I set posX, posY and posZ (object coordinates) using

```
gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, modelviewM, projectionM, viewportA, &posX, &posY, &posZ);
```

from:

```
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelviewM);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionM);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewportA);
```

I don't change any matrix value at any moment.
The problem is that the return values of gluUnProject for posX, posY and posZ are all -1.0

In adition, I should say that modelviewM and projectionM values are the identity matrix and viewportA value is (0, 0, 1440, 720)

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your projectionM should map the frustum (left,right,top,bottom,near,far) to [-1,1]x[-1,1]x[-1,1]. Now look at the value domain of projectionM*world_vector, if projectionM = diag(1,1,1,1). You may also find [SongHo's Projection Matrix article](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Debuging the program,  I can see that my projectionM 4x4 matrix value is the identity matrix. The same as the modelviewM 4x4 matrix.
I'm using glOrtho() instead of glFrustum().

Comment: The point is not whether it's a frustum or a cube; the point is that you don't it map to [-1,1]x[-1,1]x[-1,1] with an identity projection matrix.  Just read the article I pointed you to.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, I believe the `gluUnProject` function accepts values in the range -1..+1, not 0..width and 0..height.  So,

```
gluUnProject(
    ((double) winX + 0.5) / (double) width * 2.0 - 1.0,
    ((double) winY + 0.5) / (double) height * 2.0 - 1.0,
    winZ,
    modelviewM,
    projectionM,
    viewportA,
    &posX, &posY, &posZ);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried your code and it still doesn't work.

Now values for posX, posY and posZ are -1.001386..., -1.002770... and -1.0 respectively.

Actually I don't understand your explanation entirely.
According to the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml), _gluUnProject_ function accepts values between (0'0 .. window_width) for winX and (0'0 .. window_height) for winY.

Anyway, could you explain why do you do those operations to the first 2 parameters of _gluUnProject_?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED: my silly mistake was that I was calling gluUnProject() in the main() function.
I've replace it just after winZ assignation, in the mouseMove() function.
It works!
The only doubt I have now is why posZ value doesn't change. I'm using
`glReadPixels(int (winX), int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);`
to get winZ value.